# 1+ array output in Smarty

Tags: loops, foreach, smarty

I need to output following array

object(stdClass)#6 (14) { ["subcategories"]=>
 array(9) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#31 (13) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" 
["parent_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(8) "Soup" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(4) "supy" ["meta_title"]=> string(8) "Soup" ["meta_keywords"]=> string(8) "Soup" ["meta_description"]=> string(0) "" ["image"]=> string(0) "" ["visible"]=> string(1) "1" ["position"]=> string(1) "7" ["path"]=> array(2) { [0]=> *RECURSION* [1]=> *RECURSION* } ["children"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(10) } } [1]=> object(stdClass)#32 (13) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["parent_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(7) "sashimi" ["meta_title"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["meta_keywords"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["children"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(10) } } [1]=> object(stdClass)#32 (13) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["parent_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(7) "sashimi" ["meta_title"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["meta_keywords"]=> string(12) "Сашими" ["meta_description"]=> string(0) "" ["image"]=> string(0) "" ["visible"]=> string(1) "1" ["position"]=> string(1) "8" ["path"]=> array(2) { [0]=> *RECURSION* [1]=> *RECURSION* }

i think that here is multiple foreach need for output each ["name"] from ["subcategories"]

Now i've the following code

```
 {foreach name=cats from=$category->name item=n}

    <li>
        <a href="catalog/{$n->url}" category_id="{$n->id}">
            <b>{$n}</b>
        </a>

    </li>
{/foreach}
```

which displays only one Name of the current category (Soup).
How can i output each ["name"] from ["subcategories"] ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need a foreach for every level:

```
 {foreach name=cats from=$category->name item=n}

    <li>
        <a href="catalog/{$n->url}" category_id="{$n->id}">
            <b>{$n}</b>
        </a>
        {foreach name=subcats from=$n.subcategories item=s}        
        ....
        {/foreach}


    </li>
{/foreach}
```

or maybe  is **from=$n->subcategories**, I'm not sure, as you put all the array in a single line and it's difficult to see it